# SQL Server transaction count

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT 
BEGIN TRAN T1    
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT  
    BEGIN TRAN T2               
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT  
    ROLLBACK TRAN T2        
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT 
ROLLBACK TRAN T1   
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

I want to discuss on @@trancount for a moment. There are five @@trancount. The first one has value 0 . The 2nd one has value 1. the third one  has value 2.before the fourth trancount ,it encounters an error(as there is no save checkpoint for the rollback) so the value 2 will continue. Upto this I am getting the logic . Problem comes  at the last @@trancount as it should also  encounter an error (according to my half knowledge) as there is no savepoint for the rollback and hence it should retain the value 2. But instead of that it shows the output as 0. Please help me to know why the last trancount is 0 instead of 2.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: Your script is failing, ROLLBACK TRAN transaction_name must refer to the outermost transaction name, otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `SAVE TRAN` or rollback will affect entire transaction since there were no savepoints defined.

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT 
BEGIN TRAN t1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT  
    BEGIN TRAN T2
    SAVE TRAN T2 --<<
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT  
    ROLLBACK TRAN T2
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT 
ROLLBACK TRAN t1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx

> The BEGIN TRANSACTION statement increments @@TRANCOUNT by 1. ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION decrements @@TRANCOUNT to 0, except for ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION savepoint_name, which does not affect @@TRANCOUNT. COMMIT
>   TRANSACTION or COMMIT WORK decrement @@TRANCOUNT by 1.

Nice article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4451/SQL-Server-Transactions-and-Error-Handling

**Figure 1**: A COMMIT always balances a BEGIN TRANSACTION by reducing the transaction count by one.
[image]

**Figure 2**: A single ROLLBACK always rolls back the entire transaction.
[image]

> Savepoints offer a mechanism to roll back portions of transactions. A
>   user can set a savepoint, or marker, within a transaction. The
>   savepoint defines a location to which a transaction can return if part
>   of the transaction is conditionally canceled. SQL Server allows you to
>   use savepoints via the SAVE TRAN statement, which doesn't affect the
>   @@TRANCOUNT value. A rollback to a savepoint (not a transaction)
>   doesn't affect the value returned by @@TRANCOUNT, either. However, the
>   rollback must explicitly name the savepoint: using ROLLBACK TRAN
>   without a specific name will always roll back the entire transaction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . But I want to discuss on @@trancount for a moment. There are five @@trancount. The first one has value 0 . The 2nd one has value 1. The third one  has value 2.before the fourth trancount ,it encounters an error(as there is no save checkpoint for the rollback) so the value 2 will continue. Upto this I am getting the logic . Problem comes  at the last @@trancount as it should also  encounter an error  as there is no savepoint for the rollback and retain 2. But instead of that it show the output as 0. Please help me to know why the last trancount is 0 instead of 2.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where the problem is. T1 is the entire transaction. Surround it with `BEGIN TRAN EXEC('...source from answer...') SELECT @@TRANCOUNT ROLLBACK` and you will get an error about missing savepoint for T1. Because it became a nested transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`ROLLBACK TRAN` transaction_name must refer to the outermost transaction name, otherwise it will fail. You can fix your script like this

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT 
BEGIN TRAN T1    
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT  
    BEGIN TRAN T2               
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT  
    ROLLBACK TRAN T1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT 
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
   ROLLBACK TRAN T1   
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

Please note that you can use `COMMMIT TRAN T2`